# Windows script for automation

Tags: windows

About 20 years ago, when I used MAC, it had the ability to let you perform some actions in applications and saved the actions to a script that you could just double-click to execute again.

Is there something like this for Windows 7?

ex; I need to switch between 2 sound sources on my computer. Right now, I have to load the control panel, select sound and make the changes. It would be cool to have a script I could just double click to do this for me.

lee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [Autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [winautomation](http://www.winautomation.com/)?

Windows also has an automation API: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I accepted your answer because I see there apparently is not any functionality like I described above, and these are the closest thing. I was hoping to find something much easier since this is a simple task that only requires a few clicks.

Comment: Yeah, scripting in windows is something of a sorry situation.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of winautomation. Great piece of software.